# Java XStream convert XML to Object

Tags: java, xstream

I am using [XStream](http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html) to convert XML string to Java Object.

I have a huge set of data but I am posting the minimal code below:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
xstream.alias("data", DetList.class);
xstream.alias("i", Details.class);
String s = new String("<data>\n"
           +"\t<i Name='asia' type='continent' id='11'></i>\n"
           +"\t<i Name='africa' type='continent' id='12'></i>\n"
           +"\t<i Name='japan' type='country' id='13'></i>\n"
           +"</data>");
System.out.println(s);
DetList data = (DetList) xstream.fromXML(s);
```

When I debug, **data** is always **null**.

Here is my DetList class:

```
public class DetList {
    private List<Details> detlist;

    public List<Details> getDetlist() {
        return detlist;
    }

    public void setDetlist(List<Details> detlist) {
        this.detlist = detlist;
    }
}
```

And my Details class:

```
public class Details {

    private String Name;
    private String type;
    private String id;

    //Getters and Setters are here.
}
```

**data** is null which is supposed to contain the list of **i**.

How can I get it to work?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS No, there is no errors. I'm sure that I'm missing something but not sure what.

Comment: You have the getters and setters for the `name` variable? Also it should be `name` istead of `Name`

Comment: I did that, it does not have any affect.

Comment: Have a look (http://x-stream.github.io/annotations-tutorial.html ) if you want to use `@attributes` , your question has multiple errors . One is that it is expecting `items` instead of attributes in the `<i> </i>` element.

Comment: Ok thanks I will look at it

Answer (score 1):

Here is your error in case you are interested . I will replace it as soon as i find the answer :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$UnknownFieldException: No such field application.DetList.i
---- Debugging information ----
message             : No such field application.DetList.i
field               : i
class               : application.DetList
required-type       : application.DetList
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /data/i
line number         : 2
version             : 1.4.9
-------------------------------
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.handleUnknownField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:524)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:375)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:281)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1230)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1214)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1085)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1076)
    at application.Tester.main(Tester.java:15)
```